# October CMS Reflection Exception on Z-Ray

Tags: php, laravel, zend-server, octobercms

When I load my October installation on a server with Z-Ray, I get this error:

// used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.

```
if ($concrete instanceof Closure)
{
    return $concrete($this, $parameters);
}

$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

// If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
// an abstract type such as an Interface of Abstract Class and there is
// no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
if ( ! $reflector->isInstantiable())
{
```

The error come from this line: `$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);`

As a `ReflectionException`.

I don't know why it's do that, but on XAMPP, this is not present.

URL: [With Z-Ray](http://october.azurewebsites.net/index.php) and [without Z-Ray](http://october.shost.ca/). Same files, copy/pasted.

Thanks

Comment: give a try: composer dump-autoload    in root folder of app

Comment: @num8er There are no composer.json in October. Or the file as not been loaded.

Comment: sorry but how it autoloads classes from vendor folder?

Comment: seems like the issue of octobercms: https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/799

Comment: @num8er Like this : http://pastebin.com/Fpac3WT4

Comment: I know about it, but as You see that autoloader could not find the auth class. at least You can add line that like this: http://joxi.ru/jnAyeekUPvpdAZ  to file vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Comment: Do you know where is the `auth.php` file?

Comment: no, but have You looked for it?

Comment: I have found [`AuthManager.php`](https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/classes/AuthManager.php), it's return the same error and `Cannot redeclare class Backend\Classes\AuthManager`

Comment: I have added info @num8er. Check the question.

Comment: which version of PHP You're using?

Comment: @num8er I have found the answer, so feel free to reproduce it to gain 50 points (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The Laravel plugin was causing a conflict with October CMS.

**How I found this?**
First, there was this error, with this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Zray55\0.9.6\plugins\Laravel\1.0.0\zray\zray.php(122): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('auth') #5 C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Zray55\0.9.6\plugins\Laravel\1.0.0\zray\zray.php(27): ZRay\Laravel->loadUserPane
```

After, I have remarqued that the laravel panel was blank, but with numbers.

Thanks to @num8er who takes its times to help me resolve this!